# command \o is invalid in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am using textlive2014 (and I had the same error in 2013 and before though). Only now I decided to do anything about it.

Whenever I type a formula containing `$\o$` I get the warning `Command \o is invalid in mathmode`. But it displays fine, specifically, it gives the empty set symbol but with a small `o` instead of `O`.

What causes this warning? How can it be gotten rid of? Is there now a different command for the empty set with lowercase o instead of `\o` and the warning means I am using an outdated command? `$\O$` never gives me any problems and no problems in the output either way, only a warning in the `$\o$` case...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`amssymb` defines `emptyset`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\Emptyset}{\text{\o}}
\begin{document}
  \verb|\text{\o}|:
  \[
  \text{\o}
  \]
  %
  \verb|amssymb|'s \verb|\emptyset|:
  \[
  \emptyset
  \]
  %
  \verb|\varnothing|:
  \[
  \varnothing
  \]
  %
  A custom new command \verb|\Emptyset|:
  \[
  \Emptyset
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, a fix like this works, true. But is there a coding or fragility reason to use \varnothing and not use \o in mathmode _directly_? There must be some reason a warning is given and the usage \o in mathmode is discouraged, yes?

Comment: @GuidoJorg `\o` and `\O` are categorised as European language symbols, not as math symbols. Hence you can't use them in math mode.

Comment: @GuidoJorg - the error lies in your use of `\o` in math mode. You really ought to be using `\varnothing` or `\emptyset`. Dedicated math symbols can be endowed with information about any needed extra spacing around them. That's not the case for text-mode "accented" characters.