# How to get \^{\i} working in math enviroment

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts

My question is a like the one here: [only with different symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196312/command-o-is-invalid-in-mathmode).

With typing: `\[\^{\i}\]`  i  want to get a get a **i** with a **^** (replacing the dot) on its head.

So far, so good. Means it works (i get the symbol i wish to get) but TeXstudio (Version 2.12.10 (git 2.12.10)) gives me two warnings also:

> Command \^ invalid in math mode

and

> Command \i invalid in math mode

The command `\hat{i}` gives me an **i** with a **^** ontop. That is not excactly what i want.

The solution with `$\o$` replaced by `\varnothing or \Emptyset` seams to be the same, well maybe i'm just searching for the right word for my symbol in question?

Any suggestions?

---

**Update 1** after getting a solution form @Henri Menke

(On the left side of the equation)
The left one is the result of `\hat{\imath}` result, `\cdot`,  the right one it the result of `\^{\i}`

[image: The left one is the result of <code>\hat{\imath}</code>, the right one is the result of <code>\^{\i}</code>]

With other words:
[image: Not the same: The left one is the result of <code>\hat{\imath}</code>, the right one is the result of <code>\^{\i}</code>]
Lets assume that `\hat{\imath}` is indeed the right symbol, than i have to write `\(\hat{\imath}\)` (with math enviroment) every time i need to use it in my text for reference?

---

**Update 2** I knew that link before asking my question but it wasn't helpfull in my case. Maybe have a look [here, for looking up other unknown symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character) if you have a "similar" question (Please credit him if it helps you)

Comment: Use `\hat{\imath}`.

Comment: Please clarify what you need to obtain. Is it an upright or a slanted version of the dotless letter “i” with a hat on top? And, will you be using this symbol in text mode or in math mode?

Comment: @Mico  I think it should be itallic like every other variable in every equation too. But i have to write some text about the variables i'm using so i need to write it sometimes in my text too *With the same look*.

Comment: last question: of course, as every in-line (in text) math expression hat to be put in math environment.

Comment: @Zarko Well, i was a little bit *confused* because of course you can use `\^{\i}` without being math mode the same way. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @user167193 - If it's a symbol for a math variable, you should be using (math) italics, i.e., you should be using `hat{\imath}`. Obviously, this requires the use of math mode. Henri's answer is correct.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for clarification. I will honor him tomorrow. (Can i honor your comment/you as well?)

Comment: @user167193 - Once your reputation count is sufficiently high, you can upvote both comments and answers.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. I will if i can. :-) Good night.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the dotless version of i and j in math mode using `\imath` and `\jmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\hat{\imath}$
$\hat{\jmath}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well yes, maybe you are right. I tried you solution. I get a slighly different looking  i with a ^ head  than before. *is that correct / ok* ?
I will try to add a picture and a update to my question.

Comment: If this is the way to go to get the itallic version of the **i** with the **^** as head than i will accept your answer tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a similar tool to `\^`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\LetLtxMacro \egreg_hat:n \hat % save the original command

\RenewDocumentCommand{\hat}{m}
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
   {
    {i}{\egreg_hat:n { \imath }}
    {j}{\egreg_hat:n { \jmath }}
   }
   { \egreg_hat:n { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\hat{a}+\hat{i}+\hat{j}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a little bit to much for me (my purpose) but maybe others can work with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `\text{}` to escape math mode, provided by the amsmath package. So the solution would be `\^{\i}` when in text mode, and `\text{\^{\i}}` when in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$f(t) = \sin(\text{\^{\i}} \cdot t)$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Atleast this would supress the warning. You are right. But even in your example the roman **i** with the **^** head ... I don't know maybe if it represents a constant or something like that. But for my usage i'm happy with @Henri's answer.